# Command line `qdel` command with wildcard operator

Tags: linux, bash, shell, batch-processing, torque

Say I have a list of jobs scheduled on a cluster and I want to remove some of those jobs.

Normally I would use [`qdel`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/qdel) followed by the job number.

However, I'd like to delete 10s of jobs so I thought I could use `*` as a wildcard operator like so:

`qdel 11763*`

I thought this would remove jobs 117630 to 117639. However I get a `illegally formed job identifier` error.

Does anyone know of a way to use wildcard operators in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like `qdel` requires explicit, individual job IDs.  But Bash has a way to generate lists of sequential numbers easily:

```
qdel {117630..117639}
```

This will expand in the shell to call qdel with all numbers in the range.  You can also do this:

```
qdel 11763{0..9}
```